# Extra pixel for enter point of scrollSpy-Class

Tags: jquery

I'm using scrollSpy (https://github.com/thesmart/jquery-scrollspy) for my site. Unfortunately the enter position for some sectors is to early. Is there any possibility to add some extra pixel so that f.e. the enter/exit will be a little later? I try to google for that but couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 0):

You can set up the top offset in [options object for the plugin](https://github.com/thesmart/jquery-scrollspy/blob/master/scrollspy.js), $.scrollSpy = function(selector, options):

```
//config object with say 100px top offset
var options = {
    "offsetTop" : 100
};

//usage
$.scrollSpy(SELECTOR, options);
```